# Isomorphy of the integer and the polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find an Isomorphism from $$\Bbb{Z}[x]$$ to the ring of the Integer.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Z [x]$. It looks like a problem. Could it be that you only want a bijection?

Comment: you question is barely understandable. But it seems what you ask is impossible. please edit and clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for an isomorphism? A bijection perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

No such isomorphism can exist.

Suppose it did. The isomorphism must satisfy $\phi(1) = 1$ and we must have
$\phi(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ (where I am identifying $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $(k,0,\cdots) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$), we have
$\phi(k) = \phi(x)$. Hence $\phi$ cannot be an isomorphism.

Comment: O.K, thank you I was not sure if there is such an isomorphism. But yet, I didn't undrstand from your proof, why $\phi(k) = \phi(x)$?

Comment: We have $k=\phi(x)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and we have $\phi(k) = k$ (since $\phi(1) = 1$), so $\phi(x) = \phi(k)$.

Comment: Fine, now it's clear, thank you very much.